# HTMLElement to HTMLImageElement

Tags: html

What should I be doing in order to be able to use .src ? My goal is just setting the src of an image to a certain link (link changes depending on what the id is). I'm not sure if there's an easier way to do this.

I'm getting the error:

> property src does not exist on type HTMLElement

when I try to do this:

```
document.getElementById("icon" + i).src = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + weatherIconIds[i] + ".png"
```

I've found from other StackOverflow posts that I need to somehow convert my HTMLElement to an HTMLImageElement, but I'm having trouble doing so. Other posts recommend to declare the variable as an HTMLImageElement, but I didn't have to declare any variables in my HTML?

The HTML relevant to that is:

```
<img src="" id="icon0" alt="" height="40" width="40">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("icon" + i).setAttribute("src","http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + weatherIconIds[i] + ".png");
```